# Visualizing networks in GWT

Tags: gwt, processing, graphviz, jung, neato

I'd like to integrate network visualization into my GWT app.

I was thinking of using JUNG (check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279197/port-jung-into-gwt/5520023#5520023)) or neato to do the layout work and GWT-Graphics to do the drawing. It's also possible to combine GWT-Graphics with Processing and use a Processing library for networks. What would you suggest?

EDIT: The GWT Google Group suggests using a JSNI [wrapper](http://weltermann17.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/jit-gwt-a-low-cost-solution-2/) around jit (JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit). There's also a project called [raphaelgwt](http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/) that serves as a wrapper for RaphaelJs (it does cross-platform vector graphics).

Comment: I think it's a really cool idea and I'd love to see the results!

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll definitely post a link once we release!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to chat about providing GWT support to JUNG, drop me a line.  It's been proposed in the past but we don't have the time to do it ourselves soon.