# port JUNG into GWT

Tags: java, gwt, graphing, jung

there is a very good java graphing library [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)

I wonder if there exists any GWT library that does what JUNG do ? i'm aware there exist a commercial Javascript graphing library [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html). But [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) is very expensive and have a very restrictive licensing policy.

does anyone knows of any GWT graphing library similar to mxGraph (JS) or JUNG( java)?

if there is no GWT library for graphing like JUNG, I'm keen on porting JUNG into GWT. I was thinking to use gwt-graphics library as a basis and extend it with more JUNG like features .
what is a good strategy to port JUNG into GWT? should i rewrite most of JUNG java classes into client GWT classes? would there be a way to wrap JUNG classes inside some client side GWT classes ? I guess b/c JUNG uses the java swing framework ,the porting will require to migrate most UI JUNG classes (swing based) into GWT based widgets.

any Ideas or suggestions about this subject?

Best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you have to first check the licensing policy for JUNG. That might already limit out some options. IIRC, the licence is Apcahe 2.0.

As you mentioned, drawing you must re-implement. For that there a few options: [GWTCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas), [GWT Graphics](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-graphics/) and [g2d](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-g2d/), and probably others that I forgot.

Also, to take full benefit of the GWT approach must not rely on too many external projects, which makes a bit harder.

Based on all these, I would go for using only some of the classes and porting them to GWT one by one. Maybe starting from the graph layout algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer. may i ask what the Apache License limitations are? I'm not that familiar with all the licensing policies. but i guess JUNG will allow porting its source code to GWT ?

Comment: @othman: JUNG is BSD licensed, see http://sourceforge.net/projects/jung/ So the license should not be a problem (both BSD and Apache licenses have very few restrictions - but please read them yourself, they're relatively short.)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I Read the Apache and BSD licenses. they look ok for me. I couldn’t find any restrictions to use their source code (even if you intend to ship your new code in a commercial product).

Comment: I'm not familiar with BSD license details, but if you are considering open sourcing your work, there should be no problem. This could make a popular OS project itself.

Comment: Thanks eeq. I hope i could start working on this project soon. Yes i'm planing to make it OS. Hope to open a project  soon on google code projects. You are welcome to join if you are interested to participate in this effort. Best

Answer (score 3):

Check out this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952504/visualizing-networks-in-gwt).

It would be very nice to have a GWT presentation layer for JUNG. The approach we've been taking is to use [RaphaelGWT](http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt) (wrapper for [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/)) for drawing and JUNG for layout on the server side. We tried to port JUNG to the client side (where everything is translated into Javascript) but reliance on concurrent libraries and parts of the JRE made this unfeasible.

On the server side we grab the data and create our own graph object (GEGraph) with Node and Connection maps. Then we put all that into a JUNG graph and call layout on it, retrieving the x and y coordinates for each node and putting that in the GEGraph. The GEGraph is then sent to the client and drawn with Raphael.

Comment: thank you that seems interesting. have you released this library? i would like to look at it if your code is open source. thanks

Comment: Hi othman. We haven't decided whether to open source our code yet. Will have to talk to the business guys (me with a different hat on).

Comment: good @dabeats - i which you good luck in project. i wish i could be part of the project development team ,but as it is a closed source system it is not possible. anyway good luck. thanks.

Comment: @debeats , can i ask you a question? beside Java and GWT what are the topics and technologies one should read about before tackling JUNG port? how did you studied the JUNG system? by reading docs or by reading actual code? could you give advice on how to prepare well for a potential project of JUNG porting to GWT? -thanks

Comment: @othman, I read through the [tutorial] (http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf) here. From there, we looked through the API (http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html) to try to get a better feel for things. Also check out the JUNG mailing list for questions clarification. I suggest RaphaelGWT for the frontend. Besides that, everything should be Java, JUNG and GWT. Make sure you know what features are most important. Porting the entire JUNG would be very difficult and time-consuming.

Comment: thanks you . it seems porting the entire jung library to GWT is indeed difficult. it was designed not for web apps bot for desktop swing apps. so porting will involve a considerable effort.