# Port connectivity Image in Java/GWT

Tags: java, image, gwt

The project I am working requires a visual stack of the product. An image showing the port connectivity. Data from an external file containing info on which port is connected to which. The program accepts the file and generates an image showing the connectivity in appropriate colors.

It needs to be done using Java and GWT.

I did a part of it using JUNG(Java Universal Network/Graph), but there were many issues.
Is there any Java library that will help e achieve this??? Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You can generate images on server side and use this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491025/how-to-get-image-with-servlet-and-display-it-using-gwt-image-class

Comment: Displaying the image is not the issue. But genarating the image showing port connectivity graphically and dynamically is the issue. I am looking for libraries in java to achieve this.

Comment: In GWT you can use Canvas to paint anything on it. And I want to notice about gwt-links library: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-links/ May be it will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

If you have not already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279197/port-jung-into-gwt/5520023#5520023).

Something like this in GWT - Mxgraph - 
**https://www.draw.io/ and http://www.jgraph.com/**

We use it by wrapping them in GWT JSNI.

Similarly you have low cost - Draw2D - http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc/#!/example/connection_drop

**Along similar lines you have**

```
    YFiles - http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfileshtml_about.html

    Raphaël - 
    http://raphaeljs.com/
    http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/

    WireIt - http://neyric.github.com/wireit/docs/index.html
```

**Some GWT Attempts -**

```
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-diagrams/
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-graph/
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-links/
```

Comment: Thanks for the Update. We picked up MxGraph more than a year ago and hence had to go with JSNI.